Twice as slow SIMD performance without extra copy
I've been optimizing some code, and stumbled across some peculiar case.
Here are the two assembly codes:
; FAST
lea         rcx,[rsp+50h]  
call        qword ptr [Random_get_float3] ;this function only writes 3 components  
movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rsp+50h]  
lea         rbx,[rbx+0Ch]  
mulps       xmm0,xmm6  
movlps      qword ptr [rbx-0Ch],xmm0  
movaps      xmmword ptr [rsp+50h],xmm0  
extractps   eax,xmm0,2  
mov         dword ptr [rbx-4],eax  

; SLOW
lea         rcx,[rsp+50h]  
call        qword ptr [Random_get_float3] ;this function only writes 3 components
movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rsp+50h]  
lea         rbx,[rbx+0Ch]  
mulps       xmm0,xmm6  
movlps      qword ptr [rbx-0Ch],xmm0  
extractps   eax,xmm0,2  
mov         dword ptr [rbx-4],eax  

Both of the versions are executed 10000 times in a tight loop (same loop code omited). As you can see, the assemblies are exactly the same, except for one extra movaps xmmword ptr [rsp+50h],xmm0 instruction in the fast version.
Actually it's a no-op, because rsp+50h will be overwritten in the next iteration:
lea         rcx,[rsp+50h]  
call        qword ptr [Random_get_float3]

What's interesting in this code is that slow version is twice as slow compared to fast while missing one extra useless instruction.
Can someone explain why?
The C++ code (compiled with MSVC v140 with VS 2022):
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <cstdlib>

__declspec(noinline) void random_get_float3(float* vec3) {
    int v = rand();
    vec3[0] = *(float*)&v;
    v = rand();
    vec3[1] = *(float*)&v;
    v = rand();
    vec3[2] = *(float*)&v;

    vec3[0] = powf(vec3[0], 1.0f / 3.0f);
    vec3[1] = powf(vec3[1], 1.0f / 3.0f);
    vec3[2] = powf(vec3[2], 1.0f / 3.0f);
}

void* randomGetFuncPtr = &random_get_float3;

// Not aligned by 16.
struct Vector3 {
    float x, y, z;
};

struct Vector3Array {
    size_t length;
    Vector3* m_Items;
};

static bool inited = false;

Vector3 scaledRandomPosExtern = Vector3{ 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f };
Vector3Array randomPositions;
#define __SLOW // comment to enable fast version.
int numObjectsExtern = 10000;

void TestFunc() 
{
  int numObjects = numObjectsExtern;
  if (!inited) {
    randomPositions = {
        10000,
        new Vector3[10000]
    };

    inited = true;
  }

  typedef void (*Random_get_float3_fptr) (__m128* __restrict);
  Random_get_float3_fptr _il2cpp_icall_func = (Random_get_float3_fptr)randomGetFuncPtr;
  Vector3 scaledRandomPos = scaledRandomPosExtern;

  __m128 scaledRandomPosVec = _mm_setr_ps(scaledRandomPos.x, scaledRandomPos.y, scaledRandomPos.z, 0.0f);

  Vector3Array* outputArray = &randomPositions;
  int* items = (int*)&outputArray->m_Items[0];

  for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++) {
    __m128 v1;
    _il2cpp_icall_func(&v1);

#ifdef __SLOW
    __m128 v3;
    v3 = _mm_mul_ps(v1, scaledRandomPosVec);
#define RESVEC v3
#else
    v1 = _mm_mul_ps(v1, scaledRandomPosVec);
#define RESVEC v1
#endif

    _mm_storel_pi((__m64*)(items), RESVEC);
    items[2] = _mm_extract_ps(RESVEC, 2);
    items += 3;
  }
}

Mirror on Compiler Explorer
Reproducable on
CPU:
AMD Ryzen 7 3700x Windows 10 19045.3930
Other Ryzen CPUs
Can't be reproducable on Intel CPUs.

The content of Random_get_float3 would be interesting. On what "3 components" is it writing?

@chtz random_get_float3 is inside closed source engine. It writes 3 components of the vector provided by the pointer. In my case I use the pointer to __m128. I can tell for sure that Random_get_float3 is not properly vectoried inside.

Can you replace it (random_get_float3) by a mock-function which produces the same behavior? Also, try to make your C++ code a [mre] (i.e., something one can copy+paste and directly compile)?

@chtz yes, I've added the example to the post, also tested against msvc v19.latest on Compiler Explorer, it reflects the changes for __SLOW define

Also interesting that if I remove 3 powf calls the perf of slow and fast version will match perfectly, so redundant writing xmm result to stack will not affect the performance in positive side.

It's not  complete no-op as the fourth component is not overwritten by your random function.  Does the same happen when you write zeros over the stack slot?

@fuz you are right, while function is not inlined and compiler doesn't have a knowledge about the called function, rewriting the stack value fully actually makes it faster.

Does the unused value of v1 in the SLOW variant maybe start with a subnormal value? In that case, the multiplication can be slow every time again. In the FAST variant it would be 0 starting from the second iteration.

@chtz yes, you are right, if I manually write 4th component of the float to zero, then the code executes much faster (same as FAST variant) with both defines. If I write denorm float value to the 4th component the code executes slow in any case. Strange that it doesn't happens on Intels

@Alex Intel has better handling for denormals I think.  I didn't even consider this possibility!

@fuz @chtz thank you for help! Really appreciate that. Clang for some reason producing suboptimal code tho, because using only 2 xmm registers, and spills scaledRandomPosVec to the stack, then using mulps xmm0, xmm0, [rsp+scaledRandomPosVec]. Usually clang is much better at optimizing SIMD, but now I'm really curious why does it happens.

Your C++ works with an uninitialized value, which technically makes it UB (I assume that is the case, even if the result of that operation is never used). Compilers may have trouble detecting that, if the value is part of a SIMD register. I would usually try to always initialize variables (i.e., also not declare them before first use) -- but that is probably also a style-question.

mulps xmm0, xmm0, [rsp+scaledRandomPosVec] is not necessary bad, if you are not bottlenecked by IO. For the linux x86_64 ABI, it more or less has to load this from memory anyways, if functions are called whose implementation is not known to the compiler (since they are allowed to destroy any SIMD register) -- I don't know for sure about Win64, but probably they reserve some registers to be saved by the callee.

@chtz yes, manually writing denorm makes the code slower, and additional movaps back to stack seems like MSVC bug (if it wouldn't it could just initialize it from the start), and clang doesn't add it either. It doesn't change anything on Intel tho no matter if 4th component is denorm or not.
Yeah, clang doesn't know if the function will touch other xmms or not, probably it tries to play safe since function is not obligated to reset touched xmm register. On windows it seems not to be the case.

@chtz: Yes, Windows x64 has a lot of call-preserved XMM regs, too many I'd say.  XMM6-15 are call-preserved leaving only 6 regs to play with without having to save/restore anything.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170#callercallee-saved-registers  .  (And yes, x86-64 System V has no call-preserved vector regs, unfortunately, which is too few for many use-cases.  XMM 6 and 7, or 14 and 15, would have been good choices.)

Thanks to @chtz and @fuz !
Turns out that this extra instruction copied the result of the multiplication where 4th component was a normal float. Without that extra instruction, 4th component of the vector was not initialized and was a denorm float which led to slower computation.
If you manually set 4th component to denorm float, then each mulps operation will be around 20% slower, while initializing 4th component with zero will remove that overhead.
On Intel CPUs it doesn't matter if the number is norm or denorm, it doesn't affect computation speed.
This extra instruction most likely a bug of MSVC optimizer, because it shouldn't be there, but accidentaly sped up the code.

Some Intel CPUs can be slowed down by denormals in some cases.  See the Sandybridge section of Agner Fog's microarch guide (https://agner.org/optimize/).  There are a few cases where there aren't penalties for denormals, and you might be hitting that.  Or maybe newer Intel CPUs remove penalties in more cases.

Also, a vector load that reloads multiple scalar stores will always cause a store-forwarding stall on Intel or AMD, so that's not great either. (What are the costs of failed store-to-load forwarding on x86?).  Much better to generate a whole vector of random floats (with a SIMD PRNG) and mask the top one to zero or something.  Or don't mask if you don't care about that element, as long as your PRNG doesn't generate denormals.

@PeterCordes so cool! Thank you for the advices
